# Slider with Aqua-Resizer in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, slider, attachment

I'm working on a wp site and now I want a slider with Aqua-Resizer.

My slider works fine at the moment. But I can't figure out how to add the Aqua-Resizer into the code.

Here is the code of my slider.

```
<div id="slides">
<div class="slides_container">
    <?php
        query_posts('post_type=sliders&p=sliderhome'); // this calls our custom post type of 'sliders' and post id
            if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php
                $attachments = attachments_get_attachments();
                $total_attachments = count($attachments);
                if( $total_attachments > 0 ) {

                    for ($i=0; $i < $total_attachments; $i++)
                    {
                    echo '<div><img src="' . $attachments[$i]['location'] . '" alt="' . $attachments[$i]['title'] . '" class="imgradius" /></div>';
                    }

                 } ?>
            <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <?php endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    ?>
</div>  
</div>
```

This is the code of Aqua-Resizer

```
<?php

$thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' ); //get full URL to image (use "large" or "medium" if the images too big)
$image = aq_resize( $img_url, 560, 310, true ); //resize & crop the image

?>

<article <?php post_class()?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

    <?php if($image) : ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image ?>"/>
    <?php endif; ?>

    ....
```

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Include the below line to functions.php

```
 require_once('aq_resizer.php');
```

Change code as

```
for ($i=0; $i < $total_attachments; $i++)
{
    echo '<div><img src="' . **aq_resize($attachments[$i]['location'], 560, 310, true )** . '" alt="' . $attachments[$i]['title'] . '" class="imgradius" /></div>';
}
```

Reference: http://www.wpsquare.com/resize-images-wordpress-using-aqua-resizer/